# If f has a slant asymptote at infinity, prove for $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ where $A\neq 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{Ax+B}=1$

Tags: limits

How would one approach a proof like this? After using the definition of a slant asymptote and a bit of manipulation, I end up at $\lim_{x\to\infty}[Ax+B(\frac{f(x)}{Ax+B}-1)]=0$. Not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: 1. Define slant asymptote. 2. Use said definition. 3. Complete problem. 4. Profit???

Comment: After using the definition of a slant asymptote and a bit of manipulation, I end up at $\lim_{x\to\infty}[Ax+B(\frac{f(x)}{Ax+B}-1)]=0$. Not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: Multiply it out...

Comment: I just factorized $Ax+B$ out though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{Ax+B}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-(Ax+B)+(Ax+B)}{Ax+B} \\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)-(Ax+B)}{Ax+B}+1\right) \\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl(f(x)-(Ax+B)\bigr)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{Ax+B}+1
\end{align}$$
What can we say about the first limit given that $y=Ax+B$ is an oblique asymptote?

Comment: Is there a way to start off with $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-(Ax+B))$ and solve the exact same thing

Comment: @mathgeek101 If you want to start with that, then just go backwards in my proof, starting with the last line. You multiply that limit by $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{Ax+B}$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$
are slant asymptotes if
$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)-g(x))
= 0$.

If $g(x)$ is linear,
then $g(x) = ax+b$
and
$f(x)-(ax+b) \to 0$.

Therefore,
for any $c > 0$
there is an $x(c)$ such that
$|f(x)-(ax+b)| < c
$
for $x > x(c)$.

Then
$|\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+b} - 1| 
< \dfrac{c}{|ax+b|}
$.

Since
$|ax+b| \to \infty$,
not only does
$|\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+b} - 1| 
\to 0
$,
but
$|\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+b} - 1| 
=O(\dfrac1{x})
$.